# I am not able to create a Hibernate session. Dont be bothered by the length, I am just including all the info to make it easy for the reader

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to get a sessionFactory by calling NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(); and I always get this following error:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]

My mapping file is :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">******</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="contacts/employee.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="contacts/responsibilitiy.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

employee>hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="contacts.employee" table="contacts">
      <meta attribute="class-description"></meta>
    <id column="contactId" name="contactId" type="long">
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property column="contactName" length="100" name="contactName" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <property column="password" length="100" name="password" not-null="true" type="string"/>
    <set cascade="all" name="groupOfResposibilities" table="employee_responsibilty">
      <key column="contactId"/>
      <many-to-many class="contacts.responsibilities" column="responsibilityId"/>

    </set>

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

responsibility,hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="contacts.responsibilities" table="responsibilities">
    <meta attribute="class-description">
        This class list of responsibilities if an employee
    </meta>
    <id column="responsibilityId" name="responsibilityId" type="long">
      <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property column="responsibilityName" name="responsibilityName" type="string"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

employee.java

```
public class employee implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long contactId;
    private String contactName;
    private String password;
    private Set<responsibilities> groupOfResposibilities = new HashSet<responsibilities>(0);

    public employee(long employeeID, String employeeName, Set c) {
        this.contactId=employeeID;
        this.groupOfResposibilities = c;
        this.contactName = employeeName;
    }

    public employee() {

    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public long getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    public Set<responsibilities> getGroup() {
        return groupOfResposibilities;
    }

    public void setContactId(long contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public void setContactName(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    public void setGroup(Set<responsibilities> group) {
        this.groupOfResposibilities = group;
    }

}
```

responsibilities.java

```
public class responsibilities implements java.io.Serializable{    

    private long responsibilityId;
    private String responsibilityName;

    public responsibilities(){

    }

    public responsibilities(String respName){
        this.responsibilityName=respName;
    }

    public long getResponsibilityId() {
        return responsibilityId;
    }

    public String getResponsibilityName() {
        return responsibilityName;
    }

    public void setResposibilityId(long resposibilityId) {
        this.responsibilityId = resposibilityId;
    }

    public void setResponsibilityName(String responsibilityName) {
        this.responsibilityName = responsibilityName;
    }


}
```

Complete Log:

```
 Caused by:org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:108)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructDefaultTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.<init>(EntityEntityModeToTuplizerMapping.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityMetamodel.<init>(EntityMetamodel.java:322)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.<init>(AbstractEntityPersister.java:485)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.<init>(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:133)
        at org.hibernate.persister.PersisterFactory.createClassPersister(PersisterFactory.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
        at startUp.NewHibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(NewHibernateUtil.java:28)
        ... 29 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.EntityTuplizerFactory.constructTuplizer(EntityTuplizerFactory.java:105)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property responsibilityId in class contacts.responsibilities
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.createSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:262)
        at org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor.getSetter(BasicPropertyAccessor.java:255)
        at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.getSetter(Property.java:335)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.buildPropertySetter(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:304)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.<init>(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:137)
        at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer.<init>(PojoEntityTuplizer.java:77)
        ... 43 more
```

Comment: Is javaassist.jar in your class path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem is your getter and setters.  Please Check with Setter for Employee Specially For groupOfResposibilities

> public Set getGroupOfResposibilities () {
>
> ```
>   return groupOfResposibilities;
> }
> ```
>
> public void setGroupOfResposibilities(Set group) {
>
> ```
>    this.groupOfResposibilities = group;
> }
> ```

Comment: The setter and getter in employee.java are fine, I checked.

Comment: No In Employee you have defined wrongly ( getGroup() ,setGroup())  for groupOfResposibilities . Use getter and setter as metioned in my answer

Comment: Oh ok, Ill try that, right now I am fixing my typos.. But thanks for the answer. Upvoted.

Comment: You were right, I have made so may typos in the code, so if i write it like 

" public Set<responsibilities> getGroupOfResponsibilities() {

     
   return groupOfResponsibilities;
    }

    public void setGroupOfResponsibilities(Set<responsibilities> group) {

        this.groupOfResponsibilities = group;
    }"
It would be correct right?

Comment: Woo, it solved the problem, thanks a lot my friend. You and jaysagar both helped alot.

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause in your code based on the stack trace

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property responsibilityId in class contacts.responsibilities
```

Please change setter method `setResposibilityId` -> to `setResponsibilityId`, it has typo, you missed letter 'n' in `resposibilityId`

It should be

```
public void setResponsibilityId(long responsibilityId) {
    this.responsibilityId = responsibilityId;
}
```

Comment: Always Welcome :) @kapilchhattani. All the best. If it works , could you please Accept it , so that it helps others to find the answer :).

Comment: Yes yes ofcourse. I am just fixing few more typos after that Il will update.

Comment: Answer and both comments upvoted, Thanks for the help both of you. This was bugging me since one hour.

Comment: Welcome :). @kapilchhattani. Have fun